# Closing relationship tag displays when no relationship found

Tags: channel-entries, relationships

I have the following code in my template, which displays articles that have been tagged as 'related' through a relationship to the current article being viewed:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog_entries" require_entry="yes" url_title="{segment_3}"}
{related_articles}

   {if related_articles:count == 1}
      <div  id="related-articles" class="row">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="col span-12"><h3>Related Articles</h3></div>
   {/if}

   <div class="col span-4">
      <h4><a href="/blog/article/{related_articles:url_title}">{related_articles:title}</a></h4>
   </div>

   {if related_articles:count == related_articles:total_count}
      </div>
      </div>
   {/if}

{/related_articles}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This works fine for articles that have a relationship set up. My problem is that on articles that do not have any related articles set up via a relationship, the closing {/related_articles} tag is displayed in the page render. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Here are some screenshots indicating the results I am getting.

Here is a test blog post that has a related article:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTz35.png

And here is a test blog post that does not have a related article:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRkv0.png

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your last conditional shouldn't be {if related_articles:count == related_articles:total_results}?  I can't find mention of what the count and other related variables would be for the relationship field, so I suspect it falls back to the same variable set as the entries loop, in which case total_results would be what you would want here.

Alternatively, I would suggest eliminating all but the title between the {related_articles}{/related_articles} tags just to see if the issue persists and then build it back up. If I had to guess, it may be something off with your conditional (such as what I mentioned above) and that then may in turn prevent the rest of the loop from rendering as expected.

Just to confirm - is related_articles a field in your blog field group?

Comment: Yes, blog_entries has a one-to-many relationship set up to other blog_entries via the 'related_articles' field. I have tried using both total_results and total_count in the final conditional, but they both return the same results.

Comment: Which version of EE? Just wondering if it may be a reported or unreported bug. It certainly looks like it should work as you have it.

Comment: We are using EE v2.6.1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the way you've structured your html would easily allow for moving the opening and closing html *outside* of your Playa loop. Then by wrapping everything in just one conditional to check for relationships you can simplify and eliminate the need to conditionally output html.

Try this instead:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog_entries" require_entry="yes" url_title="{segment_3}"}

  {if related_articles}
     <div  id="related-articles" class="row">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="col span-12"><h3>Related Articles</h3></div>
              {related_articles}
                 <div class="col span-4">
                    <h4><a href="/blog/article/{related_articles:url_title}">{related_articles:title}</a></h4>
                 </div>
              {/related_articles}
        </div>
     </div>
  {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```